# Module has no attribute error in Python

Tags: python

This is my configurations.py

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import psycopg2

db_username = 'postgres'
db_password = 'postgres'
db_host = 'localhost'
db_name = 'testdb6'

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://' + db_username + ':' + db_password + '@' + db_host +'/' + db_name,echo=True)

Session = sessionmaker()

Session.configure(bind=engine)

sess = Session()

Base = declarative_base()
```

I get an error when I try to import the sess variable.

Say, in a separate module, I try to do configurations.sess, I get a sess is not an attribute error. But configurations.Base works fine.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which error are you getting on `sess = Session()`? Also, what is `configurations`? It's not in your code.

Comment: configurations.py is the filename of the code I've posted here. I'm getting no errors when I do sess = Session()

Answer (score 1):

I assume the libraries you are using are following hte convention that

1. methods and attributes are starting with a lowercase letter
2. Classes are starting with an uppercase letter.

Keeping this in mind, your variables are not following this convention (which does not matter, it's not an error, but sometimes it helps following conventions).

Coming to your question:
sess is referring to a newly created object of class Session(). It just might not be there when you are importing. 
On the other hand, Base seems to be a method - and therefore you are imorting a method.

And after re-reading your code: The line `sess = Session()` tries to create a new object of class session - which is not what you want. Use `sess = Session`.

Comment: Tried it, but still no luck.

Comment: As I said: The sess-Variable might just not me existing when the import is executed - therefore you get the error. You could write a `get_session()` method and import it - just encapsulate the session-related code in this method.